# Get nearest continuous date period MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have this MySQL table:

```
| Date           | Room | State |
|2015-06-15      | 26   | 1     | 
|2015-06-16      | 26   | 1     | 
|2015-06-17      | 26   | 1     | 
|2015-06-18      | 26   | 1     | 
|2015-06-20      | 26   | 1     | 
|2015-06-21      | 26   | 0     | 
|2015-06-22      | 26   | 0     | 
|2015-06-23      | 26   | 1     | 
|2015-06-24      | 26   | 0     | 
|2015-06-30      | 26   | 1     | 
|2015-07-01      | 26   | 1     |
```

I want to get the first date of the beginning of useful nearest (it means continuous day, `State = 1`) booking period (for example, 2 days).

How can I do it?

Comment: please attempt *something*

Comment: You mean the soonest future date? Something like this `Select * from table where \`date\` >= now() and \`state\` = 1 order by \`date\` asc limit 1` Providing queries you've tried would help show what your issue is.

Comment: Yes but I've got to check if the period exist (continuous date)! I've tried `select *
from booking_prices
where `Data` between date('2015-06-16') AND date('2015-06-20')
AND Stato=1
AND Disponibilita>0
AND `Camera`=35
group by `Camera`
having count(*) = datediff(date('2015-06-20'), date('2015-06-16'))+1`

Comment: You should have a `checkin` and `checkout` column. That would be much easier to use (read, query, update, delete, etc.) and will give you less records.

Comment: Every records represents a day useful to book. The booking is based on many days, so in each day (it must exist), Status=1.

Comment: I want something that runs recursively this `select * from booking_prices where Data between date('2015-06-16') AND date('2015-06-20') AND Stato=1 AND Disponibilita>0 AND Camera=35 group by Camera having count(*) = datediff(date('2015-06-20'), date('2015-06-16'))+1` changing dates while it finds a useful period (with a limit of, for example, 2015-12-31). Coding this cycle with php is a little bit expensive because it will recursively query the db.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.*
FROM   dates d
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT `Date`
              FROM   dates
              WHERE  `Room` = d.`Room`
                     AND `Date` = Date_add(d.`Date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                     AND `State` = 1)
       AND d.`State` = 1;
```

for 2 Days.

```
SET @days=3;

SELECT d.*
FROM   dates d
WHERE  (SELECT Count(`date`)
        FROM   dates
        WHERE  `Room` = d.`Room`
               AND `Date` <= Date_add(d.`Date`, INTERVAL @days - 1 DAY)
               AND `Date` >= d.`Date`
               AND `State` = 1) >= @days
       AND d.`State` = 1;
```

for dynamic days value.
And the testdata I used:

```
create table Dates(
`Date` DATE,
`Room` INT DEFAULT 26,
`State` BOOL DEFAULT 0);

INSERT INTO  Dates (`Date`,`State`) VALUES
('2015-01-01',1),
('2015-01-02',0),
('2015-01-03',1),
('2015-01-04',1),
('2015-01-05',0),
('2015-01-06',1),
('2015-01-07',1),
('2015-01-08',1),
('2015-01-09',0),
('2015-01-10',1),
('2015-01-11',1),
('2015-01-12',1),
('2015-01-13',1);
```

The query returns actually all posible dates. To get only one date add a `LIMIT 1` at the end of the statement. But maybe it can be help full to get later Startdays that are Possible.
The second query returns with the testdata the following Dates:

```
2015-01-06  26  1
2015-01-10  26  1
2015-01-11  26  1
```

Comment: Are you sure, this is working? You are checking whether the following day is booked, but not, whether the previous day is not booked. See also: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/604ad/4/0

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It returns me all dates, I want the first date if the period exist. From the example above, if the period is 2 days, it will return me 2015-06-15, if period is 5, it will return me nothing (because the period doesn't exist)

Comment: It works but maybe you expected something different. You get the possible first days where the next x days have also the state == 1. You can change the state to 0 if you need all Days with state == 0. But that is not what you write in your question. And as i wrote in my answer it returns all possible startdays but you can fetch only the first result or add a LIMIT statement.